# Autload own code using composer

Tags: php, namespaces, composer-php, autoload

I'm trying to build my own composer project and am trying to test out the code to ensure it works as I start building it. I've read through dozens of tutorials and stack overflow questions, and all seem to point to that I'm doing things right, though since it's not working, I imagine I'm not.

I have a file structure of:

```
index.php
composer.json
composer.lock
vendor/
src
    \Frankenstein
         \DB
            |FrankensteinDB.php
```

and have made the composer.json look as follows:

```
{
  "autoload": {
    "psr-4" : {"Frankenstein\\":"src/Frankenstein"}
  },
  "require": {
    "enrise/frisbee": "0.1.0"
  }
}
```

FrankensteinDB.php looks like:

```
<?php

namespace Frankenstein\DB;

use Frisbee\Exception\Flingable;

class FrankensteinDB extends Flingable
{   
    public function __construct($name)
    {
        parent::__construct($name, 1337);
    }

    public function run()
    {
    }

    public function next()
    {
    }
}
```

and of course lastly, the index.php is as follows:

```
<?php

require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';

use Frankenstein\DB\FrankensteinDB;

try {
    throw new FrankensteinDB('frankenstein');
} catch (Error $e){
    $e->getCode();
}
```

every time I run the code I get `Class 'Frankenstein\DB\FrankensteinDB' not found` and I just can't figure out why. I've tried about every combination of folders in the namespace, use, and composer psr-4 part and nothing seems to work. I also am running composer update after each change to be sure the autoload files get regenerated.

Comment: The code is correct except catching `Error` instead of `FrankensteinDB`, or `\Exception`. Also, you can't see the results of `$e->getCode();`. You probably wanted to output something. Try `var_dump($e->getCode();`

Comment: @RuslanOsmanov The error I'm catching is an error from FrankensteinDB not being found, I have a special error handler for FrankensteinDB in the frisbee package.

Comment: The structure and the code you posted actually _work_ (I have tested it just now). As I mentioned, it works incorrectly, but it works without `class not found` errors. Try to reproduce it from scratch (in another directory). Try to update composer itself. Try to test it from CLI: `php index.php`.

Comment: Huh, it does indeed work. I wonder what is wrong with the folder I have it in.